# Implement accordion within table and asp:repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, accordion, repeater

I create  table inside a repeater
and the data appears correctly, it will be two records looks like in the image below.

[image]
what i want: how to make accordion when user clicks on the deposit number(Example 16), new table will appear and contain data.

this is the repeater the first repeater code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptDep"  runat="server"  >
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-condensed table-bordered table-responsive">
            <tr>
                <th>Deposit No.</th>
                <th>Custom Declaration No.</th> 
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>Goods Description</th>
                <th>Units Balance</th>
                <th>WT Balance</th>
                <th>Goods Balance Amount(LC)</th>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#">  <%#Eval("depNo") %></a></td>
            <td><%#Eval("customDec") %></td>    
            <td><%#Eval("category") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("location") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("goodDesc") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("unitsBal") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("wtBal") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("lcBal") %></td>                  
        </tr> 
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I know that it will be a second repeater, but how to implement that, or how to use foreach statement?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: asp.net C# @TaW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, I found the solution by reading this article:

[Implement Nested Repeater (Repeater inside Repeater) with example in ASP.Net using C# and VB.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-Nested-Repeater-Repeater-inside-Repeater-with-example-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)